# Different Marshal.dump output in ruby 1.9.2 vs ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, datetime, marshalling

I'm having some issues when Marshalling dates - in particular, Marshal.dump is giving me different outputs for the same date, when I run it in ruby 1.9.2 and in ruby 1.9.3

In particular, when I run:
Marshal.dump(Date.tomorrow) in ruby 1.9.2, I get: "\x04\bU:\tDate[\bU:\rRational[\ai\x03\x9D\xF8Ji\ai\x00i\x03\x19\x15#"

When I run:
Marshal.dump(Date.tomorrow) in ruby 1.9.3, I get: 
"\x04\bU:\tDate[\vi\x00i\x03O|%i\x00i\x00i\x00f\f2299161"

Is each version of ruby using a different Date format? (rational vs ??)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Marshal is not guaranteed to be compatible across different versions. From [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html):

> Marshaled data has major and minor version numbers stored along with the object information. In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number. If Ruby’s “verbose” flag is set (normally using -d, -v, -w, or –verbose) the major and minor numbers must match exactly. Marshal versioning is independent of Ruby’s version numbers. You can extract the version by reading the first two bytes of marshaled data.